# flow control/condition in SQL query (CASE)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a CMS that is multi-lingual. There are about 300 words and phrases used throughout the system that change when the user changes the selected language. English is the default language. Other languages may not, at any given point, have been completely translated. I want the English version to be the fall back on a case by case basis where a particular word or phrase has not been translated into the selected language.
(stack overflow doesn't allow the table html tag, so I will show two records using an unordered list)

```
language_id label         translation
en          your_account  Your Account
zh          your_account  您的賬戶
```

Primary key is on language_id and label

I am using PDO on MariaDB. The part of my query that I am stuck on is the if/case statement, which I know is completely wrong below, but it demonstrates what I wish to accomplish :

```
SELECT translation_result 
FROM (SELECT translation as translation_result FROM languages WHERE
label='your_account' AND language_id = 'zh')A
CASE  A.translation_result IS NOT NULL ELSE
(SELECT translation as translation_result FROM languages WHERE
label='your_account' AND language_id = 'en')B
```

Comment: There a several way to do this. could you show as an example a typical query in which you retrieve the words from translation table ?

Comment: Instead of attempting an HTML table, just paste in a text table, highlight and ctl-k or `{}` to format it as a code block. It's easiest to copy/paste for answerers to setup demonstations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do :

```
SELECT (IFNULL(ZH.translation, EN.translation)) AS translation_result
FROM languages EN 
LEFT JOIN languages ZH ON EN.label=ZH.label AND ZH.language_id = 'zh'
WHERE EN.label='your_account' 
  AND EN.language_id = 'en'
```

Since english is the master language and always populated, you make your base query on the english records, which always returns something. From what the english returns, you make a `LEFT JOIN` on the same table, for the same label but with diffrent language. If the `JOIN` is matching something (you don't have `NULL`) you use this value

But I think the query you shown is not a good example as it is not representative of what your end-queries on language table will be in the application. Normally you should make your "master" query on other table(s), and add `LEFT JOIN` queries on the `language` table(s) following the user's language
You can add a real example and I'll adapt my answer to match it.

Comment: You can replace the whole `CASE` with `IFNULL(ZH.translation, EN.translation)`.

Comment: @shmosel good catch. I am too much ANSI standard sometimes :)

Comment: Is IFNULL the same as ANSI SQL's COALESCE?

Comment: I marked this as correct because the IFNULL construct pointed me in the right direction, although the presented query was not quite the solution. . .but that's because  I was not able to display a table, showing the data structure.

Comment: @jarlh essentially. But it only takes 2 arguments.